# Select Element from DOM which is not sibling of selected e

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have `span` element selected and I want to traverse to `input:checkbox`. I have tried using `next()`,`nextAll()`,`nextElementSibling`. But as `input` element is not sibling of `span` it is not working. Any other way I can select the input element?

Below is my code:

```
<span>This element is selected via javascript</span>

<div>
  <a href="some link"></a>
</div>


<div class="mb_content">
  5 attachement
  <br />
  <span class="error_star mr_1"><b>Size:5 MB</b></span>
</div>

<div class="checker f_left">
  <label for="rec_787128222">&nbsp;</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="mb_check" /><!--i want to select this-->
</div>
```

PS: Actual structure is bit different but I can not paste it over here. This is kind of replica for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to the parent element of the selected DOM element and then select the input.

Try it like this:

```
// <the element> . <the parent> . <select the input element>
element.parentNode.querySelector('.mb_check')
```

Comment: worked like a charm!!! just to match my original html i did element.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.mb_check')

Comment: Happy to help @Pratham :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use `nextSibling()`...

```js
var el  = document.querySelector("#foo").nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.children[1];

el.style.display = 'none';
```

```html
<span id="foo">This element is selected via javascript</span>

<div>
  <a href="some link"></a>
</div>


<div class="mb_content">
  5 attachement
  <br />
  <span class="error_star mr_1"><b>Size:5 MB</b></span>
</div>

<div class="checker f_left">
  <label for="rec_787128222">&nbsp;</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="mb_check" />
  <!--i want to select this-->
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Without any checks for `null`, you can try this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.error_star.mr_1')[0].parentNode.nextElementSibling.children[1];
```

Comment: `querySelector(...)` returns a DOM element and **not** an array